# I made this directory recursion programme that should output all the file in the whole directory but it does nothing

Tags: c++, recursion, dirent.h

I made this directory recursion programme that should output all the file in the whole directory but it does nothing,
And if i try to cout<<line<<endl; I get a lot of dot's and dot's all over the place,
I am sure that i made all the fuctions fine the problem in only in ListAllFiles Probably
This is my code, pls help me figure out the problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dirent>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

void writefile(const char* file_path, string data){
    ofstream file(file_path);
    file << data;
    file.close();
}

string readfile(const char* file_path){
    ifstream file(file_path);
    string data;
    string line;
    while(getline(file, line)){
        data.append(line+'\n');
    }
    return data.substr(0, data.length()-1);
}

bool IsDir(const char *path)
{
    struct stat info;
    if(stat(path, &info) != 0)
        return 0;
    else if(info.st_mode & S_IFDIR)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

bool IsFile(string file_path) {
    if (FILE *file = fopen(file_path.c_str(), "r")) {
        fclose(file);
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        return false;
    }   
}

string ListDir(const char* _path_){
    string data;
    string path = _path_;
    if(path == "."){
        path = "";
    }
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir = opendir (_path_)) != NULL) {
        int i = 0;
        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
            string temp = (path+ent->d_name).c_str();
            data.append(temp+'\n');
        }
        closedir (dir);
    } else {
        perror ("");
        return "";
    }
    return data.substr(0, data.length()-1);
}

string ListAllFiles(const char* _path_){
    string data1 = ListDir(_path_);
    string data;
    string line;
    istringstream iss(data1);
    while(getline(iss, line)){
        if(IsFile(line.c_str())){
            data.append(line+"\n");
        }
        else if(IsDir(line.c_str())){
            data.append(ListAllFiles(line.c_str())+"\n");
        }
    }
    return data.substr(0, data.length()-1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    cout<<ListAllFiles("C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip")<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `char*` for string arguments? And you use `c_str()` more than needed. Why are you using `fopen` instead of C++ file streams? What use is the `readfile` and `writefile` functions? If they're not used then don't show them, remember the *minimal* part of your [mre].

Comment: Also if your compiler is new enough to support the C++17 standard, you could use [the C++ filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem). It have nice [directory iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) functions.

Comment: And about your current program, have you tried to *debug* it? Like using a *debugger* to step through it statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values?

Comment: I don't have the new one

Comment: I don't see any directory iteration in this code?

Comment: It's working now bois

Comment: What did you do to make it work? If you think it might be useful for others then please post an actual answer. But please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) first.

Comment: I wanted to debug the code, but my compiler (MSVS 19) has neiter a "dirent" nor a "dirent.h" include file